# Objective-C Generic : NSNumber -> NSString

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to use Objective-C Generic Features.

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *genericNumber = @[@42, @556, @69, @3.14];

        for (NSString *number in genericNumber){
            NSLog(@"%@ is %ld letters.", number, [number length]);

        }
```

But It didn't work...

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first create an array:

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *genericNumber = @[@42, @556, @69, @3.14];
```

This array contains `NSNumber` objects and the *lightweight generics* type of the array is `NSArray<NSNumber *> *`. The *lightweight* bit is important as it reminds us that Objective-C is not strongly typed at *compile time*, some type errors will not be found until *runtime*.

You then start a loop:

```
for (NSString *number in genericNumber){
```

Here you are telling the compiler that `number` will be an `NSString` reference. However the array contains `NSNumber`s but as the compiler cannot in general check that (as its Objective-C) the compiler *trusts you* and stores a reference to an `NSNumber`, **not** a reference to an `NSString`, into `number`. So here you have a type error which the compiler doesn't spot and which will cause a problem at runtime.

You continue:

```
   NSLog(@"%@ is %ld letters.", number, [number length]);
```

Here the call `[number length]` will pass the compiler, as it believes `number` references an `NSString`, but will fail at runtime as `number` references an `NSNumber` and there is no `length` method on `NSNumber`.

You can fix these as follows:

```
for (NSNumber *number in genericNumber)      // type number correctly
{
   NSString *asText = [number stringValue];  // obtain the number value as text
   NSLog(@"%@ has %ld chars", asText, asText.length);
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better keep the number as just that, and use `stringWithFormat` to get the length:

```
NSArray *genericNumber = @[@42, @556, @69, @3.14];

for (NSNumber *number in genericNumber) {
    int length = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", number] length];
    NSLog(@"%@ is %d chars.", number, length);
}
```

**Output**:

```
42 is 2 chars.
556 is 3 chars.
69 is 2 chars.
3.14 is 4 chars.
```